Have Chrome extension iframe another website and change things in the iframe
I'm creating a Chrome extension where clicking on its icon in the extension strip will open a popup. I'm iframing my website in this popup; the URL that's open in the main tab isn't particularly important for this question. As the user is interacting with the iframed website, it'll trigger logic in the extension, and I want to have the Chrome extension be able to modify the contents of the iframed website. Of course, when I tried to do this the naive way by having the extension code try to get info about the iframe, I can't because of the cross-origin nature.
I think this is possible, since I see questions like this one and its linked answers. But I'm confused as to what sort of script I need to put on which website vs the extension, and also how things might be different with Chrome extension manifest version 3.
My rough sense of what I need to do is:

Create a content script to embed into the iframed website?
When desired, have my Chrome extension send a signal/message which the content script in the iframed website can catch?

Is that correct, or do I need to go some other path?

Using a content script is the only solution. It should be declared with all_frames, example. As for communication, the content script should initiate it via chrome.runtime.connect (multiple messages) or sendMessage (single message), see the documentation.

That's making sense, thanks. But it looks like I need to target a specific tab for the message. How do I target a content script on a website that's iframed into the popup opened by the extension action (clicking on the extension's icon in the extension strip)? Does that count as a "tab"?

You don't target it because the content script initiates communication. If you use connect() you can send many messages back. With sendMessage() you can send a response once as shown in the documentation.

@woxxom helpfully pointed me in the right direction.
Here, specifically, I'm trying to have the Chrome extension's code change something on a page that's iframed in the extension's popup. I could not figure out a way to have sendMessage target the iframed page. But, using a content script to establish a long-lived connection worked.
Specifically...
In manifest.json, declare the content script:
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://which.website.to.match.com/*"],
        "js": ["content-script.js"],
        "all_frames": true
    }
    ],

In the above, the "matches" URL should be the URL pattern of the iframed page(s) where you want to make something change.
In content-script.js, open the connection:
let port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'test'});
port.onMessage.addListener((msg, port) => {

    if (msg.type == 'some-keyword') {
        // Change HTML element on the Bubble app page to reflect success
        document.getElementById('element_id_1').innerHTML = 'Success';
        // Hide another element
        document.getElementById('element_id_2').style.display = "none";
    } else if (msg.type == 'another-keyword') {
        // whatever code
    }
});


Then in another file in the Chrome extension, you can do something like this to send a message to the iframed page:
window.onload = function () {

    // Establish connection with iframed page's content script
    let iframePort; // Can be used later in this function
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
        iframePort = port;
        port.onMessage.addListener((msg, port) => {
            console.log(msg);
        });
        port.postMessage('some-keyword');
    });

    ...
    // Later on, can do:
    iframePort.postMessage('some-keyword')
}

